# Is it safe to access Message.BodyStream on a different thread from MessageQueue.Receive

Tags: .net, msmq

I suspect it is, but would like to have confirmation, preferably from an authoritative source.

I have a thread (say thread A) that loops reading messages from a MessageQueue:

```
Message message = queue.Receive();
```

It then passes the message to another thread (say thread B), and loops to wait for the next message.  Thread B processes the message, by accessing its Message.BodyStream property.

Thread A (the receiving thread) occasionally gets an exception from the Receive method.  Examples of these exceptions are:

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): Operation was cancelled before it could be completed.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive()
```

and

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int32 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback receiveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive()
```

When this happens, thread A (the receiving thread) closes and recreates the queue before continuing.

My questions are:

- Is it generally thread-safe to access Message.BodyStream on a different thread?
- If the queue is closed and recreated by thread A while thread B is processing a message and accessing Message.BodyStream, could that cause problems?
- Is closing and recreating the queue the appropriate error-recovery strategy is MessageQueue.Receive throws a MessageQueueException?
- Bonus points for any clues as to why those exceptions might be occurring.

Comment: Your stack traces don't show you processing a message.  You are trying to read one.  It isn't any different from one thread reading a file and another randomly closing the file.  Use the threading that MessageQueue explicitly supports, call MessageQueue.BeginReceive() and you get the documented ODE when you call EndReceive() after you jerked the floor mat.

Comment: @HansPassant - seems I didn't explain it very well.  The access to the MessageQueue object is going on on one thread (thread A, looping calling MessageQueue.Receivem and recreating the queue after an error).  It's only the processing of the Message returned by MessageQueue.Receive that is handed off to a different thread.   So no "jerking the floor mat" while a Receive is in progress; only while Message.BodyStream is being accessed.

Comment: I understood that was your theory, the stack traces say it is not a correct one.  That thread is busy trying to *read* a message, not process a message.